# Error consumiendo web service de la Agencia Tributaria

Tags: visual-studio, webservice, aeat-sii

Para el sii (Sistema Inmediato de Información) de la Agencia Tributaria, tenemos un aplicativo desarrollado en Visual Studio 2012 que consume sus webservices.
De un día para otro, la llamada a los webservices está generando el siguiente error:

```html
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). 
If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: 
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <title>Agencia Tributaria - Se ha producido un error</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">       
<link href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/css/xzhtcs04.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function toggle()
  {
      var o=document.getElementById("AEAT_errores_tecnicos");
   o.style.display=(o.style.display=='' || o.style.display=='none')?'block':'none';
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">   
 <div id="header">
 <div id="AEAT_header">
   <div id="topIzquierda">
    <div id="logoAEAT">
     <ul>
    <li><a target="_self" href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es"><span class="logoGobierno"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="_self" href="http://www.agenciatributaria.es"><span class="logoAEAT"></span></a>
    </li>
   </ul>      
  </div>   
  '.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

He visto múltiples respuestas sobre qué puede provocar este error: está mal el endpoint, certificado incorrecto, falta el certificado,...

Pero lo que realmente me sería útil es obtener el error completo.

Vi una foro en que se podía capturar el InnerException de la ProtocolException que se genera y obtener de ahí la respuesta, pero a mi me sale el InnerException vacío, ni depurando consigo saber como obtener todo el HTML.

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo obtener el error completo? Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Con la clase $System.Status.GetErrorText deberías poder el error completo.

Y posteriormente trocear la descripcion del error:

```
for i=1:1:Error.Count() {
    s respostaError = ##class(DVDComp.td.errorTd).%New()
    s respostaError = Error.GetAt(i)
    s Error1 = respostaError.CodigoError
    s Error2 = respostaError.DescripcionError
    s Error3 = respostaError.NumeroOrdenPartidaConError
    s Error4 = respostaError.NumeroOrdenElementoErroneo
    s Error5 = respostaError.EtiquetaConError
    s Error6 = respostaError.ValorErroneo
    s regError=regError_sep_s_"Error: "_Error1
    s regError=regError_%CRLF_"Descripción: "_Error2
    i Error3'="" s regError=regError_%CRLF_"NumeroDePartida: "_Error3
    i Error4'="" s regError=regError_%CRLF_"NumeroDeElemento: "_Error4
    i Error5'="" s regError=regError_%CRLF_"EtiquetaConError: "_Error5
    i Error6'="" s regError=regError_%CRLF_"ValorErroneo: "_Error6
    s sep=%CRLF
}
```